# Doubt on Theorem 3.35 of Banach Space Theory, Fabian et. al.

Tags: functional-analysis

In the book *Banach Space Theory* by Fabian et. al. is proven the following theorem in page 98:

[image]

Now, I've marked 3 things in order to know if they are mistakes and to ask something that I don't really get.

- For the first red mark, shouldn't it be $U=\bigcap_{b \in B_0} U_b$?
- For the yellow mark, why is it true that this two sets are disjoint?
- For the last red mark, I think is just a reference mistake, because what is in fact using is point i) of this theorem, isn't it?

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: 1, 2) Yes, it makes sense for it to be the intersection. In this way, the yellow-marked intersection is the empty set too.
3) I don't see the reference as I don't have it at hand, but yes, it seems that the item i) is sufficient.

Comment: @MatyMangoo But why is the intersection the empty set?

Comment: Oh ok.. so imagine if you have an $b_0 = a + u$ for some $b_0 \in B$ and $a \in A, u \in U$, then $a = b_0 - u \in b_0 + U \subset b_0 + U_{b_0}$, and three lines above you see that $A \cap (b_0 + U_{b_0}) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Here I have used that $-U \subset U$ as $U$ is balanced.

Comment: Does that make sense for you? (this argument would fail if $U$ were the union, since then not necessarily $b_0 + U \subset b_0 + U_{b_0}$).

Comment: But the $b_0$ you use doesn't have to be in $B_0$, so it is not true that $b_0 + U \subset b_0 + U_{b_0}$

Comment: You are completely right, I will think a little and hopefully give you a besser answer.

Comment: I think the argument would work in a metric space for example as you can simply chose $U_b$ to be constantly the sphere of radius $r := d(A;B)$ (distance between $A$ and $B$). However, I do not really know if there is a statement in LCS that assures you that you can take $U_b$ independent on the different $b \in B$. I am sorry I can't help you more.

Comment: No problem. I found how to fix it, it is enough to change $U_b$ in the open cover of $B$ by $\frac{1}{2}U_b$, and the same in the correct definition of $U$. Then, using the convexity and the fact that U is balanced it is possible to prove that the intersection is empty.